# Body class name has an ampersand

Tags: theming

I am styling a page in a Drupal 7 site that has the title "Weddings & Private Events" and a URL alias of `/weddings-private-events` but the body class name is `weddings-&-private-events` which is invalid in CSS
 See screenshot below: [image: body classes]

Is this a bug in D7? I'm using 7.26. Is there a way for me to fix this? I want to style a page specific element without using the node id which may change on export.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not a D7 bug - all core code uses [`drupal_html_class()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_html_class/7), which removes any dodgy characters (including ampersands) by running the incoming string through [`drupal_clean_css_identifier()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_clean_css_identifier/7).

Presumably your theme (or a custom/contrib module) is adding a class without sanitising it. Look for something like:

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_html(&$vars) {
  if ($node = menu_get_object()) {
    $vars['classes_array'][] = str_replace(' ', '-', $node->title);
  }
}
```

and change it to use

```
$vars['classes_array'][] = drupal_html_class($node->title);
```